# Python, sort dict based on external list

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have to sort a dict like:

```py
jobs = {'elem_05': {'id': 'fifth'},
        'elem_03': {'id': 'third'},
        'elem_01': {'id': 'first'},
        'elem_00': {'id': 'zeroth'},
        'elem_04': {'id': 'fourth'},
        'elem_02': {'id': 'second'}}
```

based on the "id" elements, whose order can be found in a list:

```
sorting_list = ['zeroth', 'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
```

The trivial way to solve the problem is to use:

```
tmp = {}
for x in sorting_list:
    for k, v in jobs.items():
        if v["id"] == x:
            tmp.update({k: v})
```

but I was trying to figure out a more efficient and pythonic way.
I've been trying sorted and lambda functions as key, but I'm not familiar with that yet, so I was unsuccessful so far.

Comment: The key function should extract the "id" value from the "jobs" entry and find the index of it in the "sorting_list" and return it. What is the problem with this approach?

Comment: I mean, as I mentioned I'm not that familiar with sorted and lambda function. For instance, I didn't know that key is automatically called on all the elements of the iterable you'e calling sorted on. Hence, I didn't really understand what the argument of the lambda function would be, and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a dictionary as key for `sorted`:

```
order = {k:i for i,k in enumerate(sorting_list)}
# {'zeroth': 0, 'first': 1, 'second': 2, 'third': 3, 'fourth': 4, 'fifth': 5}

out = dict(sorted(jobs.items(), key=lambda x: order.get(x[1].get('id'))))
```

output:

```
{'elem_00': {'id': 'zeroth'},
 'elem_01': {'id': 'first'},
 'elem_02': {'id': 'second'},
 'elem_03': {'id': 'third'},
 'elem_04': {'id': 'fourth'},
 'elem_05': {'id': 'fifth'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to sort the dict using lambda as a sorting key:

```
jobs = {'elem_05': {'id': 'fifth'},
    'elem_03': {'id': 'third'},
    'elem_01': {'id': 'first'},
    'elem_00': {'id': 'zeroth'},
    'elem_04': {'id': 'fourth'},
    'elem_02': {'id': 'second'}}

sorting_list = ['zeroth', 'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']

sorted_jobs = dict(sorted(jobs.items(), key=lambda x: sorting_list.index(x[1]['id'])))

print(sorted_jobs)
```

This outputs

```
{'elem_00': {'id': 'zeroth'}, 'elem_01': {'id': 'first'}, 'elem_02': {'id': 'second'}, 'elem_03': {'id': 'third'}, 'elem_04': {'id': 'fourth'}, 'elem_05': {'id': 'fifth'}}
```

I have a feeling the `sorted` expression could be cleaner but I didn't get it to work any other way.

Comment: This issue with that approach is that `sorting_list.index` is expensive when repeated many times

Comment: @mozway it can't really be repeated many times since it is a handcrafted list of words. For small lists, this is an entirely sufficient approach.

Comment: @Homer512 it is repeated 6 times here, so you have to search in `sorting_list` 6 times, the behavior has a worst complexity of O(n**2)

Comment: @mozway Big O notation is meaningless for small N. Feel free to ```timeit``` for micro-optimizations but clear, simple and short solutions for tiny problems are entirely valid.

Comment: @Homer512 in OP's question "*I was trying to figure out a more efficient way*", this seems relevant (the example is likely minimal). NB. not the downvoter.

Comment: I do agree there are a lot more efficient solutions if required. I wrote this answer in respect to OP trying to do it with sorted and lambda as he mentioned. It's simple so quite pythonic as well in a sense.

Comment: I really like this approach, thanks for the help! I accepted another answer because, as @mozway suggested, this is only a MWE, the actual dict I'm working with can easily have tens of thousands of elements.

Answer (score 1):

The `sorted` function costs *O(n log n)* in average time complexity. For a linear time complexity you can instead create a reverse mapping that maps each ID to the corresponding dict entry:

```
mapping = {d['id']: (k, d) for k, d in jobs.items()}
```

so that you can then construct a new dict by mapping `sorting_list` with the ID mapping above:

```
dict(map(mapping.get, sorting_list))
```

which, with your sample input, returns:

```
{'elem_00': {'id': 'zeroth'}, 'elem_01': {'id': 'first'}, 'elem_02': {'id': 'second'}, 'elem_03': {'id': 'third'}, 'elem_04': {'id': 'fourth'}, 'elem_05': {'id': 'fifth'}}
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/WorseChartreuseFonts

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OrderedDict`:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

sorted_jobs = OrderedDict([(el, jobs[key]['id']) for el, key in zip(sorting_list, jobs.keys())])
```

This creates an `OrderedDict` object which is pretty similar to `dict`, and can be converted to `dict` using `dict(sorted_jobs)`.

Comment: You might want to add that ```OrderedDict``` is only required for compatibility with <Python-3.7. dicts are now always ordered by insertion order

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what is already posted, but with error checking in case `id` doesn't appear in `sorting_list`

```
sorting_list = ['zeroth', 'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']

jobs = {'elem_05': {'id': 'fifth'},
        'elem_03': {'id': 'third'},
        'elem_01': {'id': 'first'},
        'elem_00': {'id': 'zeroth'},
        'elem_04': {'id': 'fourth'},
        'elem_02': {'id': 'second'}}


def custom_order(item):
    try:
        return sorting_list.index(item[1]["id"])
    except ValueError:
        return len(sorting_list)


jobs_sorted = {k: v for k, v in sorted(jobs.items(), key=custom_order)}
print(jobs_sorted)
```